# E2E / Functional testing webapps with multiple simultaneous users - what's the best way to do it?

Tags: testing, web-applications, selenium, functional-testing, system-testing

Say I have a webapp that:

1. uses a lot of HTML5 technologies such as websockets, transitions, local database,
   etc.
2. is realtime and highly concurrent, so that many bugs are only apparent with multiple simultaneous users creating conflicts with each other.

What is the best way to run automated E2E tests on it?  I want full E2E testing from the browser to the database for automated regression testing, to make continuous deployment possible.  For example, it seems possible to use Selenium to fire up two browsers from one script and operate them both to show up conflict bugs between two users.  I would like to know:

1. Your favourite tools for building and running this kind of test
2. Best practices for writing the tests

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost you are needing to perform functional tests on your webapp. If you have proper functional tests then they are expected to exercise all the n tiers of your app. Selenium would help in automating the functional tests for you.

From your question of firing multiple browser instances, looks like you would want to performance testing. Selenium grid, JMeter and HP Loadrunner (paid) are available to help you to automate the scenario you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I'm not looking to run multiple browsers for performance testing here, just to detect defects.  Also, the operations of the browsers must be co-ordinated by a single test.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this parallel thread and what you might draw from the answers here:

[Performance testing in continuous integration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14740831/performance-testing-in-continuous-integration/)